# Create multiple columns in summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

What is the best way to create multiple columns in `summarize(...)` (or, alternatively, in `do(...)`)?  This arises if some aggregation function returns more than one value.  An example of such a function is `quantile(...)`.

For example, suppose we have the following data

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(x = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 20)) %>%
  mutate(y = rnorm(n(), mean = sin(x))) %>%
  group_by(x.category = round(x)) ->
  Z
```

We can compute (and plot) quantiles easily:

```
library(ggplot2) # just to display results (not the focus of this question)

Z %>%
  summarize(x = mean(x),
            y25 = quantile(y, probs = .25),
            y50 = quantile(y, probs = .5),
            y75 = quantile(y, probs = .75)) %>%
  gather(Statistic, y, -x, -x.category) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = Statistic)) +
  geom_line()
```

However, the above code has two shortcomings: 1) the `quantile(...)` code must be duplicated (this would become more tedious if, say, a dozen quantiles were needed), and 2) the column names (y25, y50, y75) might not match the actual quantiles.

These problems can be fixed by leveraging the ability of `quantile(...)` to compute multiple quantiles and return them in a vector with names, as follows:

```
Z %>%
  do(as_data_frame(c(x = mean(.$x),
                     as.list(quantile(.$y, probs = c(.25,.5,.75)))))) %>%
  gather(Statistic, y, -x, -x.category) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = Statistic)) +
  geom_line()
```

However the above code seems ugly to me; in particular it requires `as.list(...)`, `c(...)`, `as_data_frame(...)`, and `do(...)` in order to do something pretty simple.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Version 1.0.0 of `dplyr` seems to make this trivial. In fact, this exact question is discussed in a tidyverse blog post: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/dplyr-1-0-0-summarise/#quantiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by [the answer of @AntoniosK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51064085) here is a solution that also places multiple numbers in a single column, but instead of converting them to a string, stores them in a list column:

```
probs <- c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)

Z %>%
  summarize(x = mean(x),
            quantile = list(quantile(y, probs)),
            prob = list(probs)) %>%
  unnest()
```

To convert the result to a wide format one can follow the above with `%>% mutate(prob = sprintf('%g%%', 100*prob)) %>% spread(prob, quantile)` (as usual).

One thing I noticed is that `unnest(...)` ignores the names on the vectors. (In fact, I had hoped that the `.id` parameter would allow me to take advantage of that, but it looks for names on the *list* not the vectors in the list).  If you really want to use those names, one approach is:

```
library(tibble)

Z %>%
  summarize(x = mean(x),
            quantile = list(enframe(quantile(y)))) %>%
  unnest()
```

which uses `tibble::enframe(...)` to capture the names into a column of a tibble.

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach when dealing with functions that return multiple values is creating a string by combining those values and then separate that string into multiple columns using the corresponding names.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(x = runif(1000, min = 0, max = 20)) %>%
  mutate(y = rnorm(n(), mean = sin(x))) %>%
  group_by(x.category = round(x)) ->
  Z

# specify quantiles
q = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)

Z %>%
  summarise(x = mean(x),
            qtls = paste(quantile(y, q), collapse = ",")) %>%   # get quantile values as a string
  separate(qtls, paste0("y_", 100*q), sep = ",", convert = T)   # separate quantile values and give corresponding names to columns

# # A tibble: 21 x 5
#   x.category     x   y_25   y_50    y_75
#        <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1          0 0.252 -0.596  0.156  0.977 
# 2          1 0.929 -0.191  0.753  1.15  
# 3          2 2.07   0.222  0.787  1.26  
# 4          3 2.95  -0.488  0.303  1.13  
# 5          4 3.92  -1.38  -0.627 -0.0220
# 6          5 4.94  -1.52  -1.08  -0.489 
# 7          6 6.03  -0.950 -0.432  0.492 
# 8          7 6.97  -0.103  0.602  1.32  
# 9          8 7.94   0.350  1.02   1.88  
# 10         9 9.00  -0.155  0.393  1.02  
# # ... with 11 more rows
```

Comment: This is a great solution, although converting doubles into strings and back again is not ideal.

Comment: In fact I added [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51084675) that uses your idea but stores multiple values in a *list* rather than in a string. Thank you for the inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for example, use the apply family:

```
Z %>%
  sapply(function(x){c(quantile(x, probs = (0:10)/10), mean = mean(x))}) %>%
  data.frame()

#                 x         x.1           y x.category
# 0%    0.001726993  0.00274735 -4.04157670      0.000
# 10%   1.495121921  2.11284993 -1.51783484      1.000
# 20%   3.450423732  4.23374999 -0.92207407      3.000
# 30%   5.366798687  6.13729078 -0.55590328      5.000
# 40%   7.424445083  8.00006315 -0.18782436      7.000
# 50%   9.607056717 10.01599003  0.09847098     10.000
# 60%  11.605829581 11.98377222  0.39765998     12.000
# 70%  13.402578154 13.95268995  0.75339699     13.000
# 80%  15.432076896 16.04652040  1.16335283     15.000
# 90%  17.759217854 17.90820096  1.64737747     18.000
# 100% 19.991569165 19.97475065  3.33769925     20.000
# mean  9.544870438 10.02387573  0.08833454      9.551
```